# Responsive width on main column using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a responsive layout with 2 colums (main & sidebar). The side bar has a fixed width and the main column's width is responsive. do to the sidebar being a fixed width, I can't set the main column to 100% without the sidebar dropping down obviously. Is there any way to let javascript calculate the width of the main column depending on browser size? (taking into account the fixed width column that should be next to it)

```css
#main {
 background-color: #0F0;
 float: left;
 height: 400px;
 width: 100%;
}
#sidebar {
 background-color: #C60;
 float: right;
 height: 400px;
 width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using CSS's `calc()` function.

```css
#main {
  background-color: #0F0;
  float: left;
  height: 400px;
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
}
#sidebar {
  background-color: #C60;
  float: right;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
</div>
```

---

If you really want to use JavaScript you need set `main`'s `width` equal to the `window`'s `width` without scrollbar (`document.body.clientWidth`) minus `sidebar`'s `width`.

Also, the function `doMath()` needs to be executed when the `window` is resized.

```js
var main = document.getElementById('main');
var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');

function doMath() {
  main.style.width = document.body.clientWidth - sidebar.offsetWidth + 'px';
}

doMath();
window.onresize = doMath;
```

```css
#main {
  background-color: #0F0;
  float: left;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
#sidebar {
  background-color: #C60;
  float: right;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
</div>
```